# What is strict class loading?

Tags: osgi, classloader

I am learning osgi framework. It says osgi works on strict class loading environment. I am unable to get what is Strict ClassLoading. Please help i am unable to get the concept

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Whoever said this needs to explain what they mean. If you post a link to the quote then maybe it can be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Strict classloading means that a module (bundle) has to explicitly specify what it needs. In OSGi this is done using Manifest headers. Import-Package lists the packages and their version ranges the bundle needs and Export-Package lists the packages and their versions the bundle offers. In the OSGi runtime you then have a classloader per bundle that wires the bundles according to the exports and imports.

You should not define these headers by hand though. There is a nice tool named bnd or in maven the maven bundle plugin from felix which does most of the work for you. In this tutorial you find how this works in practice:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/DIBZ

You will see that I actually do not define to much by hand there. So build the code and into the meta-inf/Manifest to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

strict class loading environment means that the appropriate headers of the class need to be specified. for example the class path and the import-package

Comment: sorry .. but i am unable to get what are the headers of the class?